# How to replicate data from existing cassandra node to a fresh cassandra node, so as to safely stop old node without data loss?

Tags: linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am a newbie in Cassandra and let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a one-node Cassandra 3.11.4 instance running in Linux box, which I would like to scrap. The db is connected to an application which is 24x7 live, so that I cant bear data loss.

What I am thinking is, I would like to start a new Linux box, create a Cassandra 3.11.4 node in it, and sync data from old node to this new node. Once the sync is complete, I can change the IP in my application so that I can gracefully shut down the old Linux box.

I would like to see if this is possible or if there is any better way to achieve this. Below are the configurations (uploading to pastebin since they are lengthy);

- `cassandra.yaml` (old linux box) -> https://pastebin.com/5w6sPrc2
- `cassandra.yaml` (new linux box) -> https://pastebin.com/35Vzzwqh

Then I started my new node using command below;

```
./cassandra -Dcassandra.replace_address_first_boot=172.17.0.2
```

After this, in my new Linux box, I ran `nodetool status`, which returned below output;

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  265.28 KiB  256          100.0%            3e7e600a-3512-4d88-8336-25a83519eec3  rack1
```

same command on the old linux box shows huge data.. Instead of 265.28 KiB, I can see 2 GB.

I would like to replicate the whole data to the new Cassandra. Somebody please tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what cassandra is all about. You have two approaches:

1. Just add your new node to the existing DC and then increase your replication factor on all of your keyspaces to N nodes (in your case it'll be 2). Then run a repair.
2. Alternatively, you can create a new DC and replicate the data to the new DC.

Here's what your commands would look like in the order of above:

1)

```
ALTER KEYSPACE foobar WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dcnamehere': '2' };

nodetool repair
```

You would have to do the above on every non-local system keyspace.

2)

```
ALTER KEYSPACE foobar WITH replication = { 'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dcnamehere': '1', 'newdcnamehere': '1' };

nodetool repair
```

Number 1 is simpler, but just thought I'd throw in the alternative for future reference.